# How to make a combined set of fields unique in Mongodb in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I want to create a table where two of its fields combine to form an index field. My Python code for creating the table is as follows. What I want to do is make the combined fields `course_name` and `group_name` unique so that no two groups with the same `course_name` and `group_name` can be created. Can someone please help me with this?

```
class SocialGroup(Document):
    timestamp = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    course_name = StringField()
    group_name = StringField(choices=[('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('C', 1),('D', 1), ('E', 1), ('F', 1), ('None',1)], default="None")
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can specify [indexes](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.io/guide/defining-documents.html?highlight=unique#indexes) in the `meta` dict of the class:

```
class SocialGroup(Document):
    timestamp = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    course_name = StringField()
    group_name = StringField(choices=[('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('C', 1),('D', 1), ('E', 1), ('F', 1), ('None',1)], default="None")
    meta = {
        'indexes': [
            {'fields': ('course_name', 'group_name'), 'unique': True}
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

From: http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#uniqueness-constraints

> You may also specify multi-field uniqueness constraints by using
>   `unique_with`, which may be either a single field name, or a list or
>   tuple of field names

In your case:

```
class SocialGroup(Document):
    timestamp = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    course_name = StringField()
    group_name = StringField(choices=[('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('C', 1),('D', 1), ('E', 1), ('F', 1), ('None',1)], default="None",
                             unique_with='course_name')
```

Or more complicated:

```
group_name = StringField(choices=[('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('C', 1),('D', 1), ('E', 1), ('F', 1), ('None',1)], default="None",
                         unique_with=['course_name', 'another_field', 'more_field'])
```